# Leaflet fixed pop-up position

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, leaflet, geojson

I have create my map with Leaflet exactly how I want it (with my markers and externals links).

I would like to have the popup always fixes in the top right hand corner (for an example). Is there any way to fix the popup's location ?

This is how it should be: `jsfiddle.net/expedio/z1nw3pt4/`
but i want to use other markers not the red dots..

Thank you in advance!

(It works but its not showing in a div box in the map, its showing below the map in text..)

Comment: I clearly don't understand what is the issue? it is already on right corner.

Comment: The link is not my project, but i want to look like that, i used all the same code but its not working on mine...

Comment: Then show you code also which is not working.

Comment: it is the same as at the link...:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer!

just had to change my CSS from : `display:none;` to `display:block !important;`